Potential Sign Issues in a Composite Performance Metric for Model Selection
I am analyzing the results of various machine learning models for a regression task, using four metrics: RMSE, MAE, MAPE, and $R^2$. My approach involves two types of analyses:

Individual Metric Analysis: Where each metric is considered
separately.
Composite Performance Metric Analysis: A combined metric to
determine the best model among the candidates.

The Composite Performance Metric (CPM) incorporates the standardized mean of the metrics derived from the individual results obtained through cross-validation:
$$
\begin{equation}
\text{CPM} = M_{norm}(\text{RMSE}) + M_{norm}(\text{MAE}) + M_{norm}(\text{MAPE}) - M_{norm}(R^2)
\end{equation}
$$
where
$$
\begin{equation}
M_{norm}(\text{metric}) = \frac{\text{metric} - \mu_{\text{metric}}}{\sigma_{\text{metric}}}
\end{equation}
$$
and $\mu_\text{metric}$ is the overall mean of the metric across all
models, and $\sigma_\text{metric}$ is the overall standard deviation
of the metric across all models.
The CPM prioritizes models with lower errors (RMSE, MAE, MAPE) and higher $R^2$ values. By standardizing each metric, the CPM ensures that all metrics contribute equally, allowing for a fair comparison across different models. It essentially functions as a weighted sum where each metric is equally weighted.
The Issue with Sign Changes
However, I've encountered a potential issue: during the standardization process, the signs of some metrics may change. This could lead to misleading results when calculating the CPM. For instance, if the sign of $R^2$ flips due to standardization, it might inadvertently increase the CPM, penalizing models that should be rewarded for their higher $R^2$ values.
Proposed Solution
To address this issue, I am considering the following approach:

Error Metrics (RMSE, MAE, MAPE): Since these metrics are
non-negative, I propose taking the absolute value of the standardized
metrics to ensure they always contribute positively to the CPM.
$R^2$ Metric: I suggest preserving the original sign of $R^2$ before
standardization and reapplying it afterward to maintain its intended
influence on the CPM.

Request for Feedback
Does this approach seem valid, or am I overlooking something? Are there alternative methods or considerations that might better address the issue of sign changes during standardization in the context of the CPM?

Could you explain why you are creating a composite of RMSE, MAE, MAPE & $R^2$? This is not my area, but the approach seems quite strange to me.  In general, I would think the domain and question suggests a specific loss function & metric of performance. If one had to use multiple metrics and they differed in their model ranking, my next step would be to check why they differed rather than feed them through a complex averaging step.

It was just a way to choose the "best" model among other models.

Right - but what's the logic behind it? Are you just trying to see if a new metric can be better? How will you be assessing it?

A model dominates another if it performs at least as well on all metrics and better on at least one. This analysis classifies models as dominant, intermediate, or non-dominant, akin to Pareto dominance. Some models aren't directly comparable due to varying metric performances.
After classification, CPM ranks models by consolidating metrics into a single value, establishing a total order from best to worst. This helps identify top-performing models among the dominant ones.

The goal is to achieve a total order, not a partial one. While the metric may be hard to interpret, it enables selecting the best model—the one with the lowest CPM ranking. In this setting, all the metrics must having the same weight.

"While the metric may be hard to interpret, it enables selecting the best model—the one with the lowest CPM ranking". This is begging the question, in the original sense. You are assuming that the lowest CPM value produces the best model, but that assumption needs some support. Why does this specific mathematical procedure produce the best model?

What you are describing is fine as a pedagogical exercise, but I wouldn't rely on it and I stand by my answer below. I have limited experience in this domain, however, and I hope someone with more experience chimes in as well.

Sorry, I meant not necessarily the "best" model, but rather the one with the lowest overall value across the selected performance metrics.

RMSE, MAE, MAPE & $R^2$ are used in different situations to assess and rank models because they reflect different assumptions about the nature of the problem, data, and errors. Averaging them to produce a single metric produces an uninterpretable way of ranking your models. Setting aside issues associated with $R^2$, what does the average of $z$-transformed RMSE, MAE, and MAPE mean? Lack of a simple interpretation need not be an insurmountable objection - see Huber loss for an interesting case which 'combines' different loss functions, apparently effectively. But it's worth thinking carefully about the properties of this new metric before deploying it.
In the absence of a careful examination of its properties, I would instead suggest either (i) choosing a single metric with which to assess your models based on the nature of your problem and data, or (ii) estimating all metrics, but considering why they differ in their rankings before coming to a decision about the best model instead of applying a simple rule to them all.
